# Expression in select in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, iqueryable

If I work with LINQ to Objects, I can use `Func<TIn, TOut>` in Select, like this:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => new { A = x, B = SomeFunc });
```

where `SomeFunc` is something like this:

```
Func<int, long> SomeFunc = x => x * x;
```

But working with LINQ to Entities, Func doesn't work, I must use Expression. And this code doesn't work:

```
var query = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                   .AsQueryable()
                   .Select(x => new { A = x, B = SomeExpr });
```

where `SomeExpr` is something like this:

```
Expression<Func<int, long>> SomeExpr = x => x * x;
```

How can I use Expressions in Select in query?

Comment: maby you can try the System.Linq.Expression-Class (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.aspx)

Comment: Are you open for using 3rd party packages?

Comment: Why would you want a `Func` in object projected in query?

Comment: So, that means that I can't do this with 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' ?

Comment: I want to use Func or Expression because I need to move some code to another assembly. And I want to use Expression because Func<> doesn't work with IQueryable

Comment: is that a `Custom Database Function` or what ?

Comment: It's not a function on SQL server side, but it's a kind of custom database function

Comment: You didn't answer my question. You should understand that what are you asking is not possible out of the box, so it requires some helpers to work with `Expression`s. While it's possible to write such expressions/helpers manually, a 3rd party libraries exist so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile and execute the query

```
var query2 = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                  .AsQueryable()
                  .Select(x => new { A = x, B = SomeExpr.Compile().DynamicInvoke(x) });
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I've got exception "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object DynamicInvoke(System.Object[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that x => new {...} is already the expression you pass as an argument to Select(...). Your code will work if you compile and invoke SomeExpr into the select expression.

```
Expression<Func<int, long>> SomeExpr = x => x * x;

var query = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
                      .AsQueryable()
                      .Select(x => new { A = x, B = SomeExpr.Compile().Invoke(x) });
```